# ORA-01840 при вставке в базу из Groovy

Tags: oracle, groovy

Есть инсерт, который пишет в базу:

```
clients.each{
stmt.addBatch(insert into consumer (id, creation_date) values (consumer_seq.nextval, to_date(${new Date().format('yyyy-MM-dd')}, 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
```

В итоге оракл пишет ora-01840 длина входного значения недостаточна для формата даты

Comment: `client_id` пропущен. Указано три поля, а передается только два значения. Это так и задумано или ошибка при публикации?

Comment: да просто ошибка публикации.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте кавычки для первого аргумента `TO_DATE`. Не силен в Groovy, полагаю, что это будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
... to_date('${new Date().format('yyyy-MM-dd')}', 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
```

Насколько я понимаю, ошибка возникает, т.к. эта часть выражения:

```
to_date(${new Date().format('yyyy-MM-dd')}, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

Преобразуется в следующий SQL:

```
to_date(2018-11-08, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

Первый аргумент — выражение, результат которого: число 1999. Oracle преобразовывает его в строку '1999' и затем пытается привести строку к дате по формату, что, естественно, приводит к ошибке.